# TypeScript: How to replace imports with window objects?

Tags: typescript, requirejs, commonjs, tsc, window-object

I created a TypeScript module which requires a third-party library:

```
import Dexie from "dexie";

namespace storage {
  ...
}
```

When I compile my TypeScript file, I get the following JavaScript output:

```
"use strict";
var dexie_1 = require("dexie");
var storage;
(function (storage) {
  ...
})(storage || (storage = {}));
```

I am okay with this when using the output in a Node.js environment. But for the usage in a browser I want to replace the `var dexie_1 = require("dexie");` with an object from `window` like: `var dexie_1 = window.Dexie;`.

Can I replace the `require` statement in my compiled JS with an object from `window` (global namespace)? Is there a Gulp plugin or sth. similar around?

My **tsconfig.json** is this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: you could evaluate to use requirejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) can map `require("dexie");` to `window.Dexie`.

All you have to do is to declare the following in your **webpack.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  externals: {
    'dexie': 'Dexie'
  }
};
```

Here is a **Minimal Working Example** for the sake of completeness:

**Directory Layout:**

- bower_components (directory from `bower install`)
- dist (directory from `gulp default`)
- node_modules (directory from `npm install`)
- src (directory for TypeScript source code)
- typings (directory from `typings install`)
- bower.json (Frontend dependencies)
- gulpfile.js (Build configuration)
- index.html (demo page to test webpacked code)
- index.js (primary entry point for distribution)
- package.json (workflow and build dependencies)
- tsconfig.json (TypeScript compiler configuration)
- webpack.config.json (Webpack configuration)

**src/storage.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
import Dexie from "dexie";

namespace storage {
  export function setupDatabase():void {
    let db = new Dexie('MyDatabase');

    db.version(1).stores({
      friends: 'name, age'
    });

    db.open().then(function () {
      console.log('Initialized database: ' + db.name);
    });
  }
}

module.exports = storage;
```

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "storage",
  "main": "dist/webpacked.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "dexie": "^1.4.1"
  }
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');

gulp.task('build', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('webpack', function () {
  return gulp.src('dist/index.js')
    .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
    .pipe(rename('webpacked.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', function (done) {
  runSequence('build', 'webpack', done);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="bower_components/dexie/dist/dexie.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/webpacked.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        storage.setupDatabase();
      }, false);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
window.storage = require('./dist/storage');
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "storage",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "dexie": "^1.4.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "webpack-stream": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**typings.json**

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160709114037"
  }
}
```

Note: The `node` entry comes from `typings install dt~node --global --save` and is needed for TypeScript to resolve `module` in the `module.exports` statement.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  externals: {
    'dexie': 'Dexie'
  }
};
```

**Approach:**

The TypeScript code imports `Dexie` and declares itself using the namespace `storage`. To follow the `commonjs` way of dependency management (which is declared in `tsconfig.json`), the TypeScript code needs to export the `storage` namespace as a module with: `module.exports = storage`.

Because TypeScript doesn't know the `module` object, we need to get it's definition. The `module` definition is part of the type definition for `node`, which we get from the [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/) repository with the [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) tool using `typings install dt~node --global --save`. To link node's retrieved type definition in TypeScript, we need to declare `/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />`.

After we compile our TypeScript code (using `gulp build`), we need to declare an entry point to make our code accessible. This is done in `index.js`. A successful build outputs our `dist/storage.js` file, which is referenced in `index.js`.

When having the build in place, we can webpack our code (to bundle it for a HTML5 browser). Our `webpack.config.js` maps the "require" name of our dependency (`dexie`) to an object from the global namespace (`window.Dexie`). This guarantees us, that [Dexie](http://dexie.org/) is not part of our compiled code (`dist/webpacked.js`).

Once we have the `webpacked.js`, we can use it in a browser. But we have to make sure that all external dependencies are referenced in our HTML page (that's why Dexie is also declared as a frontend dependency using [Bower](https://bower.io/)).

Answer (score 3):

> How to replace imports with window objects?

It's not possible. There are two options:

## Use global objects

In the browser, when an object is loaded by a `<script>`, your code uses it as a global variable. In TypeScript, you have to use a global declaration file. Modules are not used here, so there is no `import` to do.

## Use a bundler or a loader

You can use a bundler, [for example *Webpack*](http://www.jbrantly.com/es6-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack/). Or [a loader like *SystemJS*](http://david-barreto.com/how-to-use-typescript-with-systemjs/).